# What is the function of "using namespace std;" in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

```
using namespace std;
```

What is the function of this statement?

Does this have the same function of "include "?

Comment: In addition to the answers that are given. Nowadays you normally won't use `using namespace` anymore, instead of that, you would only use `using` one those identifiers you want to use without namespace.

Comment: Related: [some reasons to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/1452759#1452759)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One concept in `c++` are namespaces. This organizes your code in a way.

What is `using namespace std;` do now? Let us explore this by example.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; // important line
    return 0;
}
```

You see the `std` keyword in the line with the comment. This is called a namespace. So you tell the compiler, you want to use `cout` from the namespace `std`.

With `using namespace std;`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; // important line
    return 0;
}
```

There you tell the compiler, to open the `std` namespace four you in this scope. So you can use `cout` without the `std::`. This could be mistaken to be more efficent to code. But you will run into problems at one point.

In the namespace `std` are hunderts or thounsands of functions or constants and so on defined. Most of the time you won't bother with that. But if you define a function with the same name and parameters at one point, you hardly will be able to find the mistake. For example there is `std::find`. There may be a chance you define the same function. The compiler errors in this case are a pain. So I would strongly discurage you to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: To save the pain of compiling errors, but grant your the time it would've taken to write 5 characters, you can also simply use `using std::cout;` and `using std::endl` - you'll still need to qualify things like `std::find`, `std::max`, but you can then just write `cout`

Comment: @Tas This would be an way. My point of view is, it is better style and taste to use `std::` everywhere. So everybody knows what is going on. Anyway, in the long run, it is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

It is not same function of "include". This statement allow you access any class, function or type defined in the std namespace without typing "std::" before name of class or function.

Example: if you want to declare a variable of string type in std namespace

Without "using namespace std;"

```
#include <string>
...
std::string str1;
std::string str2;
```

with  "using namespace std;"

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
...
string str1;
string str2
```

Answer (score 1):

The using directive `using namespace std` makes names within namespace `std` candidates for matching names used in the current scope.

For example, in

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
}
```

The name `vector` exists within namespace `std`  (as a templated class).   In `main()` when it sees usage of the name `vector`, the previous `using namespace std` causes the compiler to look in `std` for names that match `vector`.   It finds the `std::vector`, so uses that - and `v` then has actual type `std::vector<int>`.

The using directive does not have the same function as a preprocessor `#include`.   In the above, the `#include <vector>` is replaced by the preprocessor with the content of the standard header named `<vector>`.   The content of that header declares the templated `std::vector` class and things associated with it.

If you remove the `#include <vector>` from the above sample, and leave the `using namespace std` in place,  the code will not compile, since the compiler does not have visibility of the content of `<vector>`.

Conversely, if you remove the `using namespace std` but keep the `#include <vector>`, the code will not compile, since the name `vector` is in namespace `std` and that namespace will not be searched for names to match `vector`.

Of course, you could change the code above to

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
}
```

in which case the usage of `std::vector` explicitly tells the compiler to look in namespace `std` for the name `vector`.

There are also circumstances in which it is inadvisable to use `using namespace std`, but I'll leave finding out about that as an exercise.